# what is the open and closed loop function of this system?

Tags: control, control-system, feedback, closed-loop, control-loop

[image]

i found this in the text book.

i solved by:

1- found the closed loop function of just the part of B(p) and its "feedback", let's call it B'(p).

2- after that i did H(p) = A(p) / ( 1 + A(p) * B'(p) )

but in the textbook they solved with H(p) = A(p) * B(P) / ( 1 + A(P) * B'(p) )

so why do you think that is?

***this is a screenshot of the textbook solution***

[image]

***the writing is in French, so please ask if you wanna a little explication***

PS: sorry i am not familiar with English technical terms since we study in French here.

Comment: The one in the text book looks like the transfer function of \$\text{Feedback}(p)/E(p)\$ (but not exactly). What is the *definition* of \$H(p)\$ ? is it \$S(p)/E(p)\$ or something else ? If it is a textbook, can you add a screenshot of this question ?

Comment: H(p) is S(p)/E(P) yes.

Comment: @AJN i've added a screenshot sir

Comment: Line #3 seem to say \$B^{'}(p) = \frac{S(p)}{X(p)}\$. But then line #4 seems to say \$B^{'}(p) = \frac{X(p)}{\epsilon(p)}\$. But the screenshot you have added does not tell the *definition* of H(p). Also, I think there is a small typing error in your post. `H(p) = A(p) * B` **no dash here?** `(P) / ( 1 + A(P) * B'(p) )`. Please correct the question if it is a typing mistake.

Comment: Show the full question.

Comment: @AJN sorry, my bad

so, H(P) = S(P)/E(P). and then we have B'(p) = S(P)/X(P), this is so we can simplify the system to just a forward and a feedback loop.

after that, i think we have to calculate H(p) as A(p)/ (1 + G(p)). with G(P) = A(P) * B'(P).

is this clear?.

Comment: @Chu . there is only one question.
give the expression of H(p) = S(p) / E(P). with:
S(p) is the output
E(p) is the entry
H(p) is the closed loop function.

Comment: So, \$H(p)=\frac{p+2}{s^2+3p+4}\$